# Real operations in LaTex

Tags: latex

This is a piece of my code.

```
\newcommand{\number}{2}
\number + 2
```

Is there any way that a '4' is written instead a '2+2'? (LaTex does the real operation).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possibilities to do calculations in latex. Just one option is pgfmath:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
\newcommand{\mynumber}{2}
\pgfmathparse{\mynumber+2}

\pgfmathresult

    
\end{document}
```

Comment: And would it be possible to save the result in a command to use it later? the first way I thought was \newcommand{\result}{\pgfmathresult}; but if I do this more than once the last result overwrites the previous ones.

Comment: @PepitoGrillo `\let\result\pgfmathresult` or directly safe the result as a macro: `\pgfmathsetmacro{\result}{\mynumber+2}`